# bookdown figure number formatting

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

By default, the [{bookdown}](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/) package formats figure and table captions as, [for example](https://bd-reprex.netlify.app/intro.html):

> Figure 2.1: Here is a nice figure!

Is there a way to remove the `:` following `Figure 2.1` or to change it to any arbitrary character (e.g., `.`):

> Figure 2.1. Here is a nice figure!

I can change the `Figure` label to any arbitrary text as described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html); however, I have not been able to find documentation for customizing the separator between the figure number and caption.

From the source code [here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/5782b2ffaeea5d6ee7f34562b596d55f70824192/R/html.R#L655), I fear that the colon is hard-coded in. Any suggestions or resources are greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's indeed hard-coded, but I'll be happy to provide an option to change it. Please feel free to file an issue to the Github repo (someone might have filed it before---I don't remember it clearly now). Thanks!

Comment: For those who may be tracking this, the issue is here: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/929